# How do I install mcrypt extension for php 7.1 on MacOS 12 for Laravel development?

Tags: laravel, mcrypt, php-7.1

This is driving me crazy and following all the online tutorials hasn't helped.

I have just upgraded to a new mac running MacOS Sierra (10.12.1) and am trying to get my development environment configured. However, whenever I run composer update or composer install on my project I get the following message:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.0.35 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.35].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.35 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - laravel/framework v5.0.35 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - tom-lingham/searchy 2.0.10 requires illuminate/support 5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.35].
    - Installation request for tom-lingham/searchy 2.0.10 -> satisfiable by tom-lingham/searchy[2.0.10].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php.ini
```

I have run brew install mcrypt and it is already installed.

```
Warning: mcrypt-2.6.8 already installed
```

The system is running php 7.1 so I have also run brew install php71-mcrypt

extension=mcrypt.so has been included in the php.ini files, both on my machine and I have tried it inside the vagrant machine.

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been at this for 2 days now!

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running vagrant, you need to install mcrypt within the vagrant machine. check which version of php you have installed on vagrant and install mcrypt using

```
sudo apt-get install *{mcrypt-version-here}*
```

restart apache using

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! Worked perfectly. Can't believe it was that simple. Legend

Answer (score 1):

I had troubles of installing mcrypt-1.0.3 with PHP 7.1 on MacOS 12 Monterey.

```
 ~/projects/rest-api php -v      
PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Jun  7 2022 17:45:50) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.33, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

`pecl install mcrypt-1.0.3` and `pecl install --force mcrypt-1.0.3` failed with next error:

```
...
configure: error: mcrypt.h not found. Please reinstall libmcrypt.
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/mcrypt/configure --with-php-config=/opt/homebrew/opt/php@7.1/bin/php-config --with-mcrypt' failed
```

But I managed to install it with next command:

`pecl install --force mcrypt-1.0.3 <<<"$(ls -d $(brew --prefix)/Cellar/mcrypt/* | tail -1)"`

Last lines of result:

```
...
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.33_4/pecl/20160303/mcrypt.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mcrypt-1.0.3
Extension mcrypt enabled in php.ini

~/projects/rest-api php -m | grep mcrypt                                                  
mcrypt
```

Please see solution [source](https://programmierfrage.com/items/how-to-enable-or-install-mcrypt-extension-for-cake-php-without-xampp-or-etc).